# strange output in J creator

Tags: java, jcreator

Hi I am putting together an assignment for school and am getting a very strange output from it. the program compiles fine, but I check the output it gives me this:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more          details.

Process completed.
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong here as it looks good by both my friend and myself.

The source code, (Bearing in mind the program is not yet completed) is here:

```
/*
Assigone113.java Assignment
Written By Some Guy
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
public class AssigOne113
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    //Final variables//
    final int CURRYR=2013;
    final int SNKYR=2013 /* | 2001 | 1989 | 1977 | 1965 | 1953 | 1941 | 1929 |  1917 | 1905 | 1893 | 1881 | 1869 | 1857 | 1845 |
                    1833 | 1821 | 1809 | 1797 | 1785 | 1773 | 1761 | 1749 | 1737 | 1725 | 1713 | 1701 | 1689 | 1677 | 1665 |
                    1653 | 1641 | 1629 | 1617 | 1605 | 1593 | 1581 | 1569 | 1557 | 1545 | 1533 | 1521 | 1509 | 1497 | 1485 |
                    1473 | 1461 | 1449 | 1437 | 1425 | 1413 | 1401 | 1389 | 1377 | 1365 | 1353 | 1341 | 1329 | 1317 | 1305 |
                    1293 | 1281 | 1269 | 1257 | 1245 | 1233 | 1221 | 1209 | 1197 | 1185 | 1173 | 1161 | 1149 | 1137 | 1125 |
                    1113 | 1101 | 1089 | 1077 | 1065 | 1053 | 1041 | 1029 | 1017 | 1005 | 993 | 981 | 969 | 957 | 945 | 933|
                    921 | 909 | 897 | 885 | 873 | 861 | 849 | 837 | 825 | 813 | 801 | 789 | 777 | 765 | 753 | 741 | 729 | 717|
                    705 | 693 | 681 | 669 | 657 | 645 | 633 | 621 | 609 | 597 | 585 | 573 | 561 | 549 | 537 | 525 | 513 | 501|
                    489 | 477 | 465 | 453 | 441 | 429 | 417 | 405 | 393 | 381 | 369 | 357 | 345 | 333 | 321 | 309 | 297 | 285|
                    273 | 261 | 249 | 237 | 225 | 213 | 201 | 189 | 177 | 165 | 153 | 141 | 129 | 117 | 105 | 93 | 81 | 69 | 57|
                    45 | 33 | 21 | 9 | 2025 | 2037 | 2049 | 2061 | 2073 | 2085 | 2097 | 2109 | 2121 | 2133 | 2145 | 2157 |
                    2169 | 2181 | 2193 | 2205 | 2217 | 2229 | 2241 | 2253 | 2265 | 2277 | 2289 | 2301 | 2313 | 2325 | 2337 |
                    2349 | 2361 | 2373 | 2385
                    */;
        //Variables//

        Scanner keyboard;
        Scanner birthday;
        Scanner birthyear;

        String progstart;
        String Uname;
        String restartprog;
        String season = "springtime";
        String DD;

        double DDMM;

        int Essscore=0;
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;

        char Yeschar;

        boolean loopstart;

        //SAMMY SNAKES SIXTH/SEVENTH SPRING OF SUCCESS START//
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("<------------------------------------------->");
        System.out.println("Sammy Snakes Sixth/Seventh Spring Of Success");
        System.out.println("<------------------------------------------->");
        System.out.println(" ");

        //ASK FOR USAGE INPUT//
        System.out.println("I can calculate an Ess-Score for you"); 
        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate an Ess-Score?");
        keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        progstart=keyboard.next();
        Yeschar=(progstart.charAt(0));

        if (Yeschar=='y')

            {
                loopstart=true;
            }   

            else
                {
                loopstart=false;
                }
        while (loopstart==true);

        //USER NAME INPUT//
        System.out.println("To begin, what is your name?");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Uname = keyboard.next();
        if (Uname.charAt(0)== 'S');


}       

 }
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: That output is what happens if you were to simply type `java` into a command line. Afraid I can't give you more than that. Did you mess around with any parameters or settings in jCreator?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if the main class is not correctly configured, to fix it

Go to Project->Project Settings->In the run combo box select your main class and click ok.

[image]

If project settings is grayed out it means and you are creating the file in standalone mode  and you cannot select the main class hence you have to create a new project.

BTW, JCreator is not a good IDE for java development and has many bugs. It is not open source.
Switch to Eclipse of Netbeans or intellij Idea community edition at some point, you would never regret.

Comment: Thanks guys, as per the first comment I did not have the class figured correctly, hence the garbage it was spitting back at me. All solved cheers

Answer (score 0):

Configure main class,delete all .class files and run the program again.